# Connecting to a S3 bucket from a Redshift Cluster in Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-vpc

If the Redshift cluster resides in a public subnet with an internet gateway, do I need an S3 VPC endpoint, NAT gateway or a NAT instance to be able to UNLOAD data from Redshift cluster to a S3 bucket? I would appreciate it if you could briefly explain.

Answer (score 0):

When your cluster resides in a public subnet you do not need anything.

Because When Internet Gateway attached to your subnet. so you can access S3 bucket.

---

**S3 Endpoint / Nat Gateway**

s3 vpc endpoint is to access a s3 bucket from private subnet. For example when you launch your resources in private subnet and you want to access s3 bucket you do not need Nat Gateway to access the S3 bucket. Before the endpoint concepts in AWS if you need to access s3 it required Nat Gateway for Subnet.

Nat Gateway or Nat Instance is to access the internet from private subnet.

Comment: Although my test Redshift cluster is in a public subnet with an internet gateway, AWS Glue service still needs a VPC endpoint to connect to S3 bucket. Why can't it use the internet gateway ?